# JMETER Execute request for PUT body properties in random manner

Tags: jmeter

I have below PUT body with randomized values

```
{
     "DDSAccount": "${__property(DDSAccount)}",
     "Fundtype": "${__property(fundtype)}",
     "GeographicFocus": "${__property(geographicfocus)}" 
}
```

Executing the request will update every time all these properties with random values. However I need not to update all 3 props but to do this in the random manner. For example:
1 execution – updating only "DDSAccount": "${__property(DDSAccount)}",
2 execution – updating "DDSAccount": "${__property(DDSAccount)}" and "Fundtype": "${__property(fundtype)}",
3 execution – updating "Fundtype": "${__property(fundtype)}" and  "GeographicFocus": "${__property(geographicfocus)}",
and so on....
Is there  a way to implement this logic? Thanks for help!

I think on implementing it with csv but not sure how to do it exactly  `

Comment: I found the solution . Placed data in CSV and used bzm - Random CSV Data Set Config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options is constructing your request dynamically using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), example code:

```
def payload = [:]

switch (vars.getIteration()) {
    case 1:
        payload.put('DDSAccount', props.get('DDSAccount'))
        break
    case 2:
        payload.put('DDSAccount', props.get('DDSAccount'))
        payload.put('Fundtype', props.get('fundtype'))
        break
    case 3:
        payload.put('DDSAccount', props.get('DDSAccount'))
        payload.put('Fundtype', props.get('fundtype'))
        payload.put('GeographicFocus', props.get('geographicfocus'))
}

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

1. Put the JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which you need to parameterize
2. Put `${payload}` to the "Body Data" tab of the HTTP Request sampler.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 different samplers, which will update single parameter.
create Interleave Controller and put all three samples under it.